# Problems using htmldate with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a small script with Python in Anaconda to use htmldate, and when I try to run it I have some errors:

The code is this one:

```
import htmldate as hd
hd.find_date('http://blog.python.org/2016/12/python-360-is-now-available.html')
```

And the error is `ImportError: cannot import name etree` . I have check with pip list if I have lxml installed and I can see I have the version 4.5.2, so what happen?. Thanks so much . I have Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the python cannot find the `lml` package.

To fix this, try uninstall and then install lxml:

```
python -m pip uninstall lxml
python -m pip install lxml
```

Comment: I still have the same problem after reinstall lxml

Comment: Another thing I am seeing is that with Anaconda Navigator, through Spider IDE I have this error, but if I do it from console, everything works

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling, I clean the cache from Anaconda and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good spot. I didn't have this issue, but I was doing it through VS Code!